# Printing Out a Word Starting with a Particular String

Tags: python-3.x

I could use some help with my below code. I am trying to read through the file mbox-short.txt line by line. Looking at each word in the line to see if it starts with the string "SAK-", if so  print it out and continue. Right now my code is finding all the lines with SAK, but instead of just printing out the SAK- string it's showing everything else following the string as well.

```
fname = input('Enter File: ')
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
lst = list()

fhand = open(fname)
for line in fhand:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line.startswith('SAK'): continue
    words = line.split()
    print(words)
```

Comment: `words = line.split()` ends up being a list. Since you are only grabbing lines that start with the string you are looking for, you can simply use `print(words[0])` to index the first item within your list and print just the `'SAK-12###'` string.

Comment: Thanks for your help @A Magoon, that did the trick!